# Flutter How to show a message when flutter search filter result no result

Tags: flutter, textformfield, search-form

I'm using a `TextFormField` to filter an array of lists using `GridView` to display the Items. Inside my `TextFormField` there I used `onChanged: onSearchTextChanged,` which filters through the array response from the Rest API I created which is in `json`. The filter works fine but I'm looking for a way around showing no result when the user inputs a filter that is not available inside the filter. Below is my code:

TextFormField is as below:

```
TextFormField(

         controller: controller,
         keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
         onChanged: onSearchTextChanged,

             decoration: InputDecoration(
               border: InputBorder.none,

               contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 15.0, 20.0, 15.0),
           prefixText: ' ',
           hintText: "Search",
           hintStyle: TextStyle(
               color: Colors.grey,fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
               fontSize: 15,
               fontFamily:
               'Montserrat'),
           prefixIcon: Container(
               child:Icon(
                 Icons.search,
                 color: Colors.grey,
                   size: 20,
               )),

           suffixIcon: backClear==true?InkWell(
               onTap: () {
                 controller.clear();
                 onSearchTextChanged(
                     '');
               },
               child: Container(
                   child:Icon(
                     Icons.backspace,
                     color: Colors.grey,
                     size: 12,
                   ))): Container(
               child:Icon(
                 Icons.view_list_rounded,
                 color: Colors.grey,
                 size: 15,
               )),


           labelStyle: new TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),

         ),
       )
```

onSearchTextChanged is as below:

```
onSearchTextChanged(String text) async {
    _searchResult.clear();
    if (text.isEmpty) {
      setState(() {

        backClear=false;

      });
      return;
    }

    content.forEach((userDetail) {
      if (userDetail.username.toLowerCase().contains(text) || userDetail.username.toString().contains(text) ||
           userDetail.username.toUpperCase().contains(text)||userDetail.fullname.toLowerCase().contains(text) || userDetail.fullname.toString().contains(text) ||
           userDetail.fullname.toUpperCase().contains(text)||userDetail.phone.toLowerCase().contains(text) || userDetail.phone.toString().contains(text) ||
           userDetail.phone.toUpperCase().contains(text)||userDetail.email.toLowerCase().contains(text) || userDetail.email.toString().contains(text) ||
           userDetail.email.toUpperCase().contains(text) ) {
        _searchResult.add(userDetail);
      }

    });

    setState(() {

      backClear=true;


    });


  }
```

For instance if `John` is not part of the return array list for `username, fullname` then on the screen it should show a message that says `not found`.

My gridview is as below:

```
Container(

      child: _searchResult.length != 0 ||
      controller.text.isNotEmpty
      ?new GridView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),

          itemCount: _searchResult == null ? 0 : _searchResult.length,
          gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount:3),
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){

            return Card(
                elevation: 1,
                semanticContainer: true,
                child:InkWell(
                    onTap: () async {


                    },
                    child: Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                        child:Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment:
                            CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Flexible(
                                child: Column(
                                  children: <Widget>[

                                    Stack(

                                      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,

                                      children: [
                                        CircleAvatar(
                                          radius: 30,
                                          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                                          child: _searchResult[index].profile_img!=null?Container(
                                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                                              child:CircleAvatar(

                                                radius: 40,
                                                backgroundImage:NetworkImage(_searchResult[index].profile_img
                                                  ,),
                                                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                                                //
                                              )):Container(
                                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                                              child:CircleAvatar(

                                                radius: 40,
                                                backgroundImage:AssetImage('assets/person_icon.png'),
                                                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                                                //
                                              )),
                                        ),

                                      ],),



                                    Flexible(
                                        child:   Center(child: Text(_searchResult[index].username==null?"AppName":_searchResult[index].username,style: TextStyle(
                                          color: colorBlack,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                                          fontSize: 10,
                                          fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                                        ),))),


                                    Flexible(
                                      child:   Container(
                                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15,right: 15,top: 1,bottom: 1),
                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                            color: colorBlue,borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(3)),

                                        child: Text( "Follow",
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                            fontSize: 10,
                                            fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),)

                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ]))));
            ;})

          :GridView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),

          itemCount: content == null ? 0 : content.length,
          gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount:3),
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
            return Card(
                elevation: 1,
                semanticContainer: true,
                child:InkWell(
                    onTap: () async {


                    },
                    child: Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                        child:Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment:
                            CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Flexible(
                                child: Column(
                                  children: <Widget>[

                                    Stack(

                                      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,

                                      children: [
                                        CircleAvatar(
                                          radius: 30,
                                          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                                          child: content[index].profile_img!=null?Container(
                                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                                              child:CircleAvatar(

                                                radius: 40,
                                                backgroundImage:NetworkImage(content[index].profile_img
                                                  ,),
                                                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                                                //
                                              )):Container(
                                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                                              child:CircleAvatar(

                                                radius: 40,
                                                backgroundImage:AssetImage('assets/person_icon.png'),
                                                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                                                //
                                              )),
                                        ),

                                      ],),



                                    Flexible(
                                        child:   Center(child: Text(content[index].username==null?"AppName":content[index].username,style: TextStyle(
                                          color: colorBlack,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                                          fontSize: 10,
                                          fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                                        ),))),


                                    Flexible(
                                      child:   Container(
                                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15,right: 15,top: 1,bottom: 1),
                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                            color: colorBlue,borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(3)),

                                        child: Text( "Follow",
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                            fontSize: 10,
                                            fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),)

                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ]))));}))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the suggestion of `Dani3le_` to use add below `if` statement inside my `onSearchTextChanged` and I declare my `bool showNotFoundText = false;` above my code

```
if (_searchResult.isEmpty) {
      //Do something
      setState(() {
         showNotFoundText = true;
      });
    }
```

and above my `Gridview` I added the below to show the `No result message` find below the code:

```
showNotFoundText==true ? Text("No result found!",style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Montserrat',color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 13, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),) : Container(),
```

But `onPress` of backspace the `No result found` still shows even if the input is available on the search list so I add `showNotFoundText = false;` to `setState()` so that every time the backspace is pressd it set the state of `showNotFoundText` back to `false` as shown below:

```
setState(() {
        showNotFoundText = false;

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure on where you actually display results in your sample code, but the logic you could implement is the following.
After the `forEach` you should check if some result is actually found, and in case it wasn't, set a `showNotFoundText` to true so that in your view you can display the message.

```
onSearchTextChanged(String text) async {
    _searchResult.clear();
    if (text.isEmpty) {
      setState(() {
        backClear=false;
        showNotFoundText = false;
      });
      return;
    }

    content.forEach((userDetail) {
      if (userDetail.username.toLowerCase().contains(text) || userDetail.username.toString().contains(text) ||
           userDetail.username.toUpperCase().contains(text)||userDetail.fullname.toLowerCase().contains(text) || userDetail.fullname.toString().contains(text) ||
           userDetail.fullname.toUpperCase().contains(text)||userDetail.phone.toLowerCase().contains(text) || userDetail.phone.toString().contains(text) ||
           userDetail.phone.toUpperCase().contains(text)||userDetail.email.toLowerCase().contains(text) || userDetail.email.toString().contains(text) ||
           userDetail.email.toUpperCase().contains(text) ) {
        _searchResult.add(userDetail);
      }
    });

    if (_searchResult.isEmpty) {
      //Do something
      setState(() {
         showNotFoundText = true;
      });
    }

    setState(() {
      backClear=true;
    });

  }
```

Add something like this in your view

```
showNotFoundText ? Text("No results found") : Container() //Empty container instead
```

Since you didn't include the code for the results display, I made it this way, but you may also consider using this logic directly in your view:

```
_searchResult.isEmpty ? Text("No results found") : DisplayResultsWidget()
```

Comment: Thanks, I just updated my question with where the search result displays.

Comment: Your above solution works to an extent but when ```No results found``` displayed at the point where user input is not available the message still shows when the keyboard backspace is pressed and the left input value still shows result on my search list. For instance, I input ```Johns``` and it is not available on my search list and I remove ```s``` leaving ```john``` which is available on my search list, the ````No results found``` keeps shhowing. I modify your answer to best suit the right answer to this question.